# How can we maker color darker than given color in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Suppose i have color light red and i need more red form it could you please assist me how it is possible. I have hexadeciaml color like #00ff00

Thank you

Comment: "More Red" Pantone (c) designed by The Client.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

jQuery is not necessary in this case!

```
function ColorLuminance(hex, lum) {
    // validate hex string
    hex = String(hex).replace(/[^0-9a-f]/gi, '');
    if (hex.length < 6) {
        hex = hex[0]+hex[0]+hex[1]+hex[1]+hex[2]+hex[2];
    }
    lum = lum || 0;
    // convert to decimal and change luminosity
    var rgb = "#", c, i;
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        c = parseInt(hex.substr(i*2,2), 16);
        c = Math.round(Math.min(Math.max(0, c + (c * lum)), 255)).toString(16);
        rgb += ("00"+c).substr(c.length);
    }
    return rgb;
}
```

`hex` is the hex color value and `lum` is the luminosity factor, -1 <= lum <= 1, negative number mean darker, positive lighter

Usage:

```
var newColor = ColorLuminance("#00ff00", -0.5); // "#334d66" - 50% darker
```

See a [working JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y2mgW/)

Code snippet from [here](http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-generate-lighter-darker-color/)